# Issue in URL not showing www with domain name

Tags: magento-1.9, url, htaccess

I have issue with URL wants to add `"WWW."` before domain name or sub domain name.

URL is now shows in browser like `"http://example.com/"`

it should be `"http://www.example.com/"`

Comment: Did you change at base_url at core_config_data table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `System`->`Configurataion`->`General`->`Web`->`Unsecure` / `Secure`->`Base URL` and add change values to your domain with `www`.
[image: Configuration]

Also you can update this value directly in DB.
Open `core_config_data` table, filter rows with the following query
`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'web/%secure/base_url'`

Then change values to your domain with `www`. But be careful, base url must start with `http(s)://` and must end with `/`.

Example `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: great job bro +1 and accept. solve my issue. thanks.

Comment: can you provide certification note or any guidance i need it.